# Using multiple variables in Nginx request_uri

Tags: variables, nginx, lua, webserver, openresty

Good morning programmers, I'm trying to protect a file, and for that I just want to allow the request_uri that I define. Example:

```
if ($request_uri !~* "d=123&y=456") {
    return 403;
}
```

In this case, that example works, but I would like to do something like this:

```
set $test1 123;
set $test2 456;

if ($request_uri !~* "d=$test1&y=$test2") {
    return 403;
}
```

So I want to make it via variables, is that possible? Cause I already tested a bunch of examples and none of them worked.

**P.S: I'm using OpenResty (Nginx+Lua) so I would also accept solutions in Lua.**

As requested:
I don't remember everything I tried, since I tried a bunch of code, but I can tell you something that did worked:

```
set $teste 123;
if ($request_uri ~* "[?&]d=([^&]*)") { set $d $1; }
if ($d != $teste) {
    return 403;
}
```

The only problem on this sentence is that it only verifies for the `d=` and I wanted it to verify also the `y=`, I could do another `if` but I also wanted the `d=` and the `y=` on the same sentence instead of using multiple Ifs.
Anyway this sentence has another issue I can't change the `$d != $teste` to `$d !~*` $teste it simply stops working and I need to use the `!~*`, as last option I could use multipe ifs, but since I can't use the `!~*` it will not work anyway

Comment: Did you try "d=${test1}&y=${test2}"?

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work with "d=${test1}&y=${test2}"

Comment: Good question! Could you update your question with some of the things you've tried?

Comment: Done, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is a literal and cannot contain variables. Alternatively, you can achieve the same logic using:

```
set $test1 123;
set $test2 456;

if ($arg_d != $test1) { return 403; }
if ($arg_y != $test2) { return 403; }
```

Comment: Hello, currently I ended up using the example I gave with multiple ifs but I'm having a little problem, for example: If I use: "if ($request_uri !~* "123")" or "if ($request_uri != "123")" it works well, but with variables its another history, with variables if I use "if ($request_uri != $test1)" it also works, but if I turn the "!=" different or equal, to different or contains "!~" "if ($request_uri !~ $test1)" it simply doesn't work, but its only using variables, any issue for this little problem?